# How to maintain scroll position in Chrome and Safari in TabPanel after setting focus to control

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-applications

I am trying to maintain scroll position after setting focus to postback control across multiple browsers using the following coding. Works fine in IE but scroll jumps back to top in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari when i try to reset focus on the control that caused the postback. I set focus using the scriptmanager.setfocus(control) method.
Note: I am referring to the vertical scroll bar in the tab panel, not the main page scroll bar.

```
 Private Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
     Dim PostControl As Control = FindControlById(HiddenFieldPostControl.Value)
        If PostControl IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim sm As ScriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Master.Page)
            sm.SetFocus(PostControl)
        End If
    End If
 End Sub

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// Maintain scroll position in given element or control
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
var yPos
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    var tb = document.getElementById('MainContent_RightTabContainer_InputTabPanel');
    if (tb != null) {
        yPos= $get('InputPanel.ClientID').scrollTop;
    }
}
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    var tb = document.getElementById('MainContent_RightTabContainer_InputTabPanel');
    if (tb != null) {
        $get('InputPanel.ClientID').scrollTop = yPos;
    }
}

<asp:Panel ID="InputPanel" runat="server" CssClasss="MenuPanel" EnableViewState="False">
    ...controls
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by setting focus in javascript using postBackElement and not using the scriptmanager to set focus on server side event.  I found this code below at [Focus Scroll Issue](http://forums.asp.net/t/1622050.aspx/1/10)

Here is my updated javascript code. Also, remove sm.SetFocus(PostControl) from Page_PreRender event

```
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
// Maintain scroll position in given element or control
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------//
var yPos
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    var tb = document.getElementById('MainContent_RightTabContainer_InputTabPanel');
    if (tb != null) {
        postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement();
        yPos= $get('InputPanel.ClientID').scrollTop;
    }
}
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    var tb = document.getElementById('MainContent_RightTabContainer_InputTabPanel');
    if (tb != null) {
        $get('InputPanel.ClientID').scrollTop = yPos;
        if (postBackElement != null) {
            document.getElementById(postBackElement.id).focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the Page directive as such:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"  MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" Inherits="SomeObject" %>
```

Comment: Yes, I am already using MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback but that only applies to the page and not the scroll bar inside a tabpanel. thanks though.